# Hi! I have a shapefile with the geodata for areas within london. trying to make a tmap and include data of crime rate from a csv file how do i do this

Tags: r, csv, shapefile, tmap

So i have the shapefile with all the geodata that i need

so far my code i have tried is this

```
tm_shape(LSOA_London) + tm_fill( "$Crime_rate", palette = "spectral") + tm_border()
```

the issue i am having is that the "crime_rate" data is from a csv file and i dont know how to convert it so that it will work in my map.

do i need to rasterise the data?

any help would be great!

as shown above that is what i have tried, im yet to merge the csv with the .shp file but again im unsure on how this works. i havent done rstudio coding for a while so its all very rusty.

Comment: Hi Ahogg, welcome to SO. It is better to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/at/76995406/2530121) when asking a question. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/2530121) has some really useful guidance regarding how to create an MRE, and how to share example data in particular. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to **join** the shape data with the data in `.csv` file. As it's hard to guess the data you are using, below example based on some online data available. The join type depends on kind of the data in two datasets: either you can use `left_join()` from {dplyr} package to join on particular columns, either `left_join()` from {sf} package, if both datasets are spatial data.

The boundaries came from {geographr} package:

```r
london_lsoa <- geographr::boundaries_lsoa11
london_lsoa
#> Simple feature collection with 34753 features and 2 fields
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -6.378393 ymin: 49.88235 xmax: 1.762942 ymax: 55.81107
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#> # A tibble: 34,753 × 3
#>    lsoa11_name               lsoa11_code                                geometry
#>  * <chr>                     <chr>                            <MULTIPOLYGON [°]>
#>  1 City of London 001A       E01000001   (((-0.0972656 51.52158, -0.0947445 51.…
#>  2 City of London 001B       E01000002   (((-0.092737 51.52139, -0.088103 51.51…
#>  3 City of London 001C       E01000003   (((-0.0967596 51.52325, -0.0945333 51.…
[...]
```

And crime data from online resource:

```r
download.file(url = "https://data.london.gov.uk/download/recorded_crime_summary/11f0256e-bbde-46ca-ac49-89eaba2bd4b8/MPS%20LSOA%20Level%20Crime%20%28most%20recent%2024%20months%29.csv",
              destfile = "~/Downloads/LSOA_crime.csv",
              method = "wget",
              extra = "-c")

lsoa_crime <-
  read.csv(file = "~/Downloads/LSOA_crime.csv")
head(lsoa_crime)
#>   LSOA.Code                 LSOA.Name   Borough
#> 1 E01000006 Barking and Dagenham 016A E09000002
#> 2 E01000006 Barking and Dagenham 016A E09000002
#> 3 E01000006 Barking and Dagenham 016A E09000002
#>                         Major.Category        Minor.Category X202202 X202203
#> 1            Arson and Criminal Damage       Criminal Damage       1       0
#> 2                             Burglary     Domestic Burglary       0       1
#> 3                        Drug Offences      Drug Trafficking       0       0
#>   X202204 X202205 X202206 X202207 X202208 X202209 X202210 X202211 X202212
#> 1       0       0       0       2       1       0       0       0       0
#> 2       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       2       0
#> 3       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
```

As you can see, both datasets have a 'common' column `lsoa11_code` in boundaries and `LSOA.Code` in crime data. We can use this column to join both datasets, filter out just example column with numbers of crime and summarise it for each LSOA area:

```
lsoa <- london_lsoa |>
  dplyr::left_join(lsoa_crime, by = c("lsoa11_code" = "LSOA.Code")) |>
  subset(!is.na(X202202), select = c("lsoa11_name", "lsoa11_code", "X202202", "geometry")) |>
  dplyr::group_by(lsoa11_code) |>
  dplyr::summarise(sum = sum(X202202), .groups = "keep")

tmap::tm_shape(lsoa) +
  tmap::tm_polygons(fill = "sum",
                    fill.scale = tmap::tm_scale_intervals(n = 6,
                                                          values = "Blues")) +
  tmap::tm_borders(col = "grey60", lwd = 0.1)
```

[image]

Created on 2024-03-04 with reprex v2.1.0